# iwconfig does not show Noise Level for wireless

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I have a Dell Latitude E6410, which uses an Intel Ultimate N-6300 Wireless card. iwconfig does not show the Noise level of the wireless interface , wlan0. Does anyone know the reason for that?

```
precise@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Work/transmitter$ iwconfig  
lo no wireless extensions.

mon0    IEEE 802.11abgn Mode:Monitor Tx-Power=15 dBm
        Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
        Power Management:off

wlan0   IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"AirPennNet"
        Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: D8:C7:C8:D7:A6:C1
        Bit Rate=130 Mb/s  Tx-Power=15 dBm
        Retry long limit:7  RTS thr:off  Fragment thr:off
        Power Management:on
        Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm
        Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx  invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0  
        Tx excessive retries:800  Invalid misc:540  Missed beacon:0

eth0    no wireless extensions.
```

I tried to use `cat /proc/net/wireless` and got these results:

```
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |  Discarded packets         | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise | nwid crypt frag retry misc | beacon | 22
 wlan0: 0000   64.  -46.  -256      0     0    0   818  566        0
```

Is `-256` the noise level? How do I interpret this in dBm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that typically the [LQI (Link Quality Indicator) and RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indication)](http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/w/design_notes/calculation-and-usage-of-lqi-and-rssi.aspx) are used as relative measurements of the quality and strength.

Look at this line:

```
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off Power Management:on Link Quality=65/70 Signal level=-45 dBm
```

In particular the end of it:

```
Link Quality=65/70 Signal level=-45 dBm
```

There is the link quality and signal level, which should give an indication of how well the connection is. The link I gave above details how to interpret them, you'll want to use these instead of the noise.

---

As for the noise value, you've got that right:

```
Inter-| sta- | Quality          | Discarded packets          | Missed | WE
 face | tus  | link level noise | nwid crypt frag retry misc | beacon | 22
 wlan0: 0000    64.  -46. -256      0    0     0   818   566    0
```

Note the -46 which is your signal level (in dBm), the -256 is indeed the noise level (in dBm).

Comment: Was not the question how to read noise value?

Comment: @akostadinov: Answer updated with more information.

Comment: @akostadinov: Answer updated with more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way: [wavemon](http://freecode.com/projects/wavemon). It can be found in many distros. A nice curses based wireless information visualization program.

btw the -256 noise level seems to say that no value is returned by driver.